# Permutation group with cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm new to abstract algebra and I'm currently learning cosets. So, I came across this example in my textbook:

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $S_3$ defined by the permutations $\{(1),(123),(132)\}$. The left cosets of $H$ are
$$(1)H=(123)H=(132)H=\{(1),(123),(132)\},$$
$$(12)H=(13)H=(23)H=\{(12),(13),(23)\}$$

I'm not sure to understand how to get the second coset $\{(12),(13),(23)\}$ with the subgroup $\{(1),(123),(132)\}.$ Could someone show me the reasoning behind it?

Comment: they correspond to the three products of the form $(12)h$ where $h$ is one of the three elements of $H$.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Asinomas Okk thank you, I get it now. I have another small question: Do you know if there exists a trick to know immediately if the right cosets are equal to the left cosets with permutation groups?

Comment: @Shaun Abstract Algebra - Theory and Applications - Thomas W. Judson - August 5, 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left cosets of a subgroup $K$ of a group $G$ are defined to be

$$aK=\{ ak\mid k\in K\}$$

for each $a\in G$.

So, to get your coset, simply multiply each element of $H$ on the left by the chosen representative.

For example,

$$\begin{align}
(12)H&=\{(12)(1), (12)(123), (12)(132)\}\\
&=\{(12), (1)(23), (13)(2)\}\\
&=\{(12), (13), (23)\}.
\end{align}$$