# Find all left cosets of $\langle(12), (34)\rangle$ in $S_4.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

One of my exercises in my textbook is:

Find all left cosets of $\langle(12), (34)\rangle$ in $S_4$.

Note: $\langle x,y,\dots\rangle$ denotes the smallest subgroup containing $\{x,y,\dots\}.$

I'm not sure how to represent $H$ because of the note. Does $H = \langle (12)\rangle$ and $\langle(34)\rangle$? So, $H = \{ e, (12), (34)\}$? Which mean $| G | / | H | = 24/3 = 8$ left cosets? Then, I just need to find my cosets. I'm just not sure about the value of my $H.$

Thank you,

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: $H$ as you’ve defined it is not a subgroup.

Comment: @amWhy Ok, thank you, but what is the note's meaning, mentioning the smallest subgroup?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews H = {(1),(12),(34)} is not a subgroup of S4?

Comment: No, you are missing the product of $(12)$ and $(34)$.

Comment: @Shaun Abstract Algebra - Theory and Applications - Thomas W. Judson

Comment: @Shaun Thomas W. Judson, August 5, 2017 - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278485/permutation-group-with-cosets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $H=\{ e, (12), (34), (12)(34)\}$. There are $|S_4|/|H|=4!/4=6$ left cosets.

To find the left cosets of a subgroup $K$ of a group $G$, recall that

$$aK=\{ ak\mid k\in K\}$$

for each $a\in G$. All you need to do, then, is multiply each element of $H$ on the left by each element of $S_4$, and see which are equal.

Comment: Really?  Please check for duplicates before answering.